# Fullcalendar Json Events Feed Not Displaying Anything

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, fullcalendar

Looks like well known problem, but I still couldn't find the solution.

I am testing Fullcalendar with Scheduler on my localhost. I am trying to replace static data feed as an array with data from MySQL database. I have followed the guidelines, but events are not displaying.

Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today'
            },

            views: {
                agendaWeekly: {
                    type: 'agenda',
                    duration: { days: 7 },

                    // views that are more than a day will NOT do this behavior by default
                    // so, we need to explicitly enable it
                    groupByResource: true,

                    //// uncomment this line to group by day FIRST with resources underneath
                    groupByDateAndResource: true
                }
            },

            defaultView: 'agendaWeekly',
            lang: 'sl',

            businessHours: {
                start: '08:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                end: '22:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
            },

            allDaySlot: false,
            minTime: '08:00:00',
            maxTime: '22:00:00',

            defaultDate: '2016-03-30',
            nowIndicator: true,

            resourceLabelText: 'Igrisca',
            resources: [
                { id: '1', title: 'Igrišče 1', eventColor: 'green' },
                { id: '2', title: 'Igrišče 2', eventColor: 'green' }
            ],

            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            selectOverlap: false,

            select: function(start, end, resource) {
                var title = prompt('Rezervacija termina za (ime, tel):');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        resourceId: resourceId
                    };asas
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },

            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

            events: 'myfeed.php',

        });

    });

</script>
```

The last line of code calls external file myfeed.php, which has the following code:

```
$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'un', 'pw') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('db');
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $dblink);
$event_array = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) ) {    
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {        
        $event_array[] = array(
            'id' => $row['BookingID'],
            'title' => $row['BookingNote'],
            'start' => $row['BookingStartTime'],
            'end' => $row['BookingEndTime'],
            'resourceId' => $row['CourtID']
        ); 
        }}
echo json_encode($event_array);
```

The result of JSON is the following array:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"Goran 041\/853-184","start":"2016-03-30T19:00:00","end":"2016-03-30T21:00:00","resourceId":"1"},{"id":"2","title":"Janez","start":"2016-03-31T10:00:00","end":"2016-03-31T12:00:00","resourceId":"2"},{"id":"3","title":"Sa\u0161o","start":"2016-03-31T14:00:00","end":"2016-03-31T16:00:00","resourceId":"2"}]
```

If I manually add this array, it is working and events are shown on the calendar. But I cannot get it working via JSON. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is your 'myfeed.php' actually called or not?

Comment: YES it is. Here is a link, I have just uploaded files to the production server: http://www.slotenis.si/rezervacije/

Comment: try setting json headers `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before your echo

Comment: I have tried this one before, but no luck.

Comment: There is no myfeed.php on your site? http://www.slotenis.si/rezervacije/myfeed.php or http://www.slotenis.si/myfeed.php are 404 errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. The problem was in full path to the JSON file:

Once I  have changed it from

```
 /wp-content/themes/canvas-child/myfeed.php
```

to

```
 http://www.slotenis.si/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/myfeed.php
```

I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using events:

use

```
eventSources: getSources()
```

where getSources

```
getSources(){
 var mysources = {
   mysourceone:{
                url: YOUR URL TO GET JSON,
                type: 'POST', 
                data:{
                //SOME DATA YOU MIGHT PASS, NOT important for your problem
                 },
                 cache: false,
                 color: '#C1272D',
                 textColor: 'white'
                 }
              }
  return [mysources.mysourceone];
}
```

Comment: On your browser's network view, in response tab can you show what is coming from server ?
When you implemented my sugestion, in the same view did you see a ajax call ?

Comment: sorry, this is out of my knowledge. What exactly and how should I check it?

Comment: How do I pass the date range from current view to getSources function?

Comment: Declare a global var or pass your date range by parameter...to the function and use data:{ mydaterange: range } . Server side in the request just get request header mydaterange.